# повторный вызов ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Я осваиваю ajax, помогите разобраться.

Есть код:

**HTML:**

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.navbar-nav li').click(function(){
            var clickId = this.id;
            cleaningMenu (clickId);
            loadContent(clickId);
        });
    });

    function cleaningMenu (clickId) {
        $(".container li").removeClass("active");
        $("#loading").empty();
        $("#"+clickId).addClass("active");
    }

    function loadContent (clickId){
            $.ajax({
                url: "php/load.php",
                type:'post',
                data:{"get":"getComplex"},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var row = data[i];
                        if (clickId == "getComplex") {
                            $("#loading").append("<div class='col-xs-6 col-md-2'>" +
                                    "<a href='" + row.link + "' class='thumbnail'>" +
                                    "<img src='" + row.img + "'>" +
                                    "<h3>" + row.text + "</h3></a></div>"
                            );
                        }
                        if(clickId == "getInstructions") {

                            $("#loading").append("<div class='list-group'>" +
                                "<a href='"+row.link+"' class='list-group-item'>" +
                                row.text +
                                "</a>"+
                            "</div>"
                            );

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```php
if($_POST['get'] === "getComplex") {

# Соединение
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

# Выбор базы данных
    mysql_select_db('link_db') or die('Не могу выбрать базу данных');

# Выполнение запроса
    $query = "SELECT * from complex";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}


if ($_POST['get'] == "getInstructions"){
# Соединение
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

# Выбор базы данных
    mysql_select_db('link_db') or die('Не могу выбрать базу данных');

# Выполнение запроса
    $query = "SELECT * from instructions";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

При выборе `getInstructions` выводит данные из `getComplex`, но со стилями `getComplex`.

Прошу объяснить почему и как исправить.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Здравствуйте, вот смотрите `data:{"get":"getComplex"},` в этой строчке вы передаете статичную строку. Я думаю, нужно сделать так: `data:{"get":clickId },`

Comment: А вообще, я бы советовал генерировать html код в php. А ajax-ом получить и выводить этот код `$("#loading").append(data);`. В данном случае, все что вернет php будет добавлено в `#loading`. Но это ИМХО, так читал и так делаю, если Вы учитесь, будут полезны оба способа)

Comment: Спасибо, прислушаюсь к Вашему совету. Скажите, почему json выводит информацию не из той базы?

Comment: @VINET, я же Вам написал выше, `data:{"get":"getComplex"},` этой строчкой Вы всегда отправляете в php файл слово getComplex. Замените всю строку на: `data:{"get":clickId },` - должно работать так, как Вы хотите

Comment: Вы гений ) Спасибо! )